# Using Graph database and relational database concurrently

Tags: mysql, relational-database, graph-databases

Would there be merit in having both a graph database such as GraphDB and a relational database such as MySQL to store user information for use cases such as social media platforms?
I would imagine some operations like friend of friend are much faster in graph databases, but it seems like some more standard queries would be more efficient or easier with a standard relational DB. Is it a major waste of space and runtime for API calls to store the same information in both?

Comment: Beware:  When the dataset becomes bigger than can be cached in RAM, virtually any DB engine will bog down.

Comment: By "graph", you are not talking about line / bar / scatter / pie graphs, correct?

Answer (score 0):

The approach on putting a source of truth in Tabular DB/RDBMS and wiring application to a Graph Database(Nebula Graph, Neo4J, etc...) GDBMS is doable and actually is being used by some teams.

One of the reasons that there is no such thing, for now, to automatically persist data into the two at the same time, is the way data is being mapped from tabular DB to Graph DB(property graph model) isn't deducible:

- Not all connections are physically done, someones are logical, that requires the user to specify
- Not all fields are worthy to be persisted in Graph DB, some could be omitted/not suitable to be stored in the graph
- There should be trade-offs on whether certain information should be a vertex/node or a property, and this will be changed during the biz logic involution

You could build your own infra to sync data between the two, in a batch or real-time way, depending on your needs, and model the graph based on your requirements, then iterate the modeling during your adoptions.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to use just one database technology, one that offers both relational and graph data models. One of this is [Agensgraph](https://bitnine.net/agensgraph/) a multi-mkdel database built on top of standard PostgreSql. It support Cypher,the query language created by Neo4j.

Comment: I am using Apache AGE in PostgreSQL. Any guidance on how to spread the system model across the relational and graph capacities?